# How to export/spool large table to file in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, file-io

What are the convenient way to export/spool large table (43 million records) to single file in Oracle?

(Once we get the exported file, the purpose is to handle it in a Shell Script running in Solaris with kshell, but it is another history).

Our first try generated an empty file:

```
SET   NEWPAGE       0;
SET   LINESIZE    169;
SET   PAGESIZE      0;
SET   VERIFY      OFF;
SET   TERMOUT     OFF;
SET   COLSEP       '';
SET   FEEDBACK    OFF;
SET   HEADING     OFF;

SPOOL THE_MONSTER_FILE.txt;

SELECT
    a.field1, a.field2, b.field1, b.field2
FROM
    tableA a, tableB b,
WHERE
    a.id = b.id(+);

SPOOL OFF;
COMMIT;
EXIT;
```

Comment: The question is where you are going to use it. If it is another Oracle database, you should prefer datapump (`expdp,impdp`) rather than use a csv spool file, because the way you are doing, it may take minutes to hours depending on the resources available. Also, make it a practice of using ANSI `left join`  syntax rather than the old school `(+)`.

Comment: I just add next info to my post: (Once we get the exported file, the purpose is to handle it in a Shell Script running in Solaris with kshell, but it is another history). I aprecciate the left join hint!

Comment: If you are going to do some processing in a shell script with this raw data, you should essentially be able to do it within db, with queries and  much faster. Not sure, if you wish to do so and it again depends on your requirements.

Comment: Add `SET TAB OFF` to prevent tab alignment issues. Also `SET TRIMSPOOL OFF` to avoid trailing spaces on each line. You might also look at increasing throughout by `SET ARRAYSIZE 50` (experiment with different values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the result set into a CSV file. Create a shell script and let it running on background, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<EOF > THE_MONSTER_SCRIPT.sql
SET COLSEP ;
SET HEADSEP OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET LONG 2000000000
SET LINESIZE 1000
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET TRIMSPOOL ON

SPOOL THE_MONSTER_FILE.csv;

SELECT
    a.field1, a.field2, b.field1, b.field2
FROM
    tableA a, tableB b,
WHERE
    a.id = b.id(+);

SPOOL OFF

EXIT
EOF

nohup sqlplus system/password@INSTNAME @THE_MONSTER_SCRIPT.sql &
```

If any of the columns on the result set have the column separator in its value, you have to enclose the columns with double quotes, replacing double quotes in the column value with two double quotes. Example:

```
/*
 * ----------------
 * | col1  | col2 |
 * ----------------
 * | a"a;a | aaa  |
 * | bbb;b | b"b  |
 * ----------------
 */
```

will turn into:

```
/*
 * "a""a;a";"aaa"
 * "bbb;b";"b""b"
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do with help of SSIS packages.

Check link [Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/load-data-from-database-to-text-file-using-ssis-package/).

Comment: Thanks for the response but, twelve steps are ‘too much enough’ for us at this moment. ;-) We prefer to exhaust the SQL SPOOL tool first.